# Serilog - Include Custom Information Before JSON String for FileSink

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I have a format that I need to follow for logging. I am writing out to the FileSink with a

```
        Serilog.Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Sink(new FileSink(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serilogPath"],new JsonFormatter(), null))
            .CreateLogger();
```

This generates a per-line JSON object looking like (I formatted it, it is actually one line in the log file):

```
{
    "Timestamp": "2016-05-29T02:49:33.2153863+08:00",
    "Level": "Error",
    "MessageTemplate": "my template",
    "Properties": {
        <MyPropertiesHere>
    }
}
```

I have asked from another question that I need to specify my own json formater to remove the timestamp/level/messagetemplate, which I can do, but ultimately, what I need is something like a combination of the output of a File and a FileSink with JSON (I formatted this as well. It should be all in one line):

```
2016-06-03 11:19:33.343 +08:00 [Information] {
    "MyCustomKeyName": {
        "key1": "val1",
        "key2": "val2"
    }
}
```

With my current configuration, the JSON object is showing the correct serialized form of the object, but I need the timestamp, [Information] field (could be error/warning as well), and the ability to rename the "Properties" key to "MyCustomKeyName".

The timestamp and the [Information] information is what I get by default when using a WriteTo.File, but my goal is to obtain that from using a FileSink with json formatter. With the FileSink, I am getting one whole JSON object with the fields encapsulated inside as key/val pairs. I want to have the timestamp and level information preceding the JSON object. The goal is to have logstash parse it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing your own `Serilog.Formatting.ITextFormatter` is the way to go here; it should be fairly straightforward to reuse the Serilog `JsonFormatter` either directly or by copying the code, for the JSON part.

When you have implemented the formatter you can pass it through `WriteTo.File()` in place of the built-in `JsonFormatter`.

Comment: I'm a total scrub when it comes to C#. I just realized from your comment I could copy and paste your JsonFormatter and remove those entries, and add the text behind the JSON string to be written! Thanks a bunch, I really like how you support the package so well!

Comment: Great, glad to hear :-)